# Sanitise input for traceroute tracepath

Tags: bash, networking

Hi I'm after a way to sanitise input for traceroute/tracepath /well really any bash input.

For example:

```
root@meh:~# tracepath http://google.com/
gethostbyname2: Unknown host
```

I'll probably setup an alias in bash, but need to know how to do it first (maybe even shell script?).

Cheers!

Comment: Your question is off topic for Serverfault because it doesn't appear to relate to servers/networking or desktop infrastructure in a professional environment. It may be on topic for [Superuser](http://superuser.com) but please [search](http://superuser.com/search) their site for similar questions that may already have the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Your input is perfectly sanitary.  Your problem is that tracepath expects a hostname, not a URL.  Take a look at [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879057/bash-script-to-return-domains-instead-of-urls/11879549#11879549)

Comment: whoops yea meant to post to SU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A domain name has a limited set of valid characters.  The only one that has any special meaning to bash is the dash: `-` and conveniently, it's not valid at the start of a domain name.  You can use this regex: `"^[a-zA-Z0-9\.]\+[-a-zA-Z0-9\.]\+$"`.

There are invalid domain names that this regex will pass, such as `..` and `.-.-.-.-` but it won't pass any invalid *characters* and it won't allow a dash as the first character.  That *should* make the input safe to use as an argument to `tracepath`.

Of course, because you're validating this input as being safe for bash, you will have to do the validation in some language other than bash.  There won't be any way you could safely do this validation in bash.